# Add textfield to system branding block form to specify link URL

Tags: 8, blocks

I would like to alter the branding block to add a textfield in the block form to specify the URL it should redirect to. The URL is currently fixed to `<front>` in the Twig template.

What I've done so far is to add the text field with hook_form_alter. I'm saving the value using `$form['entity_builders']` and `$block->setThirdPartySetting`. This works.

I want to retrieve this value in `hook_preprocess_block__system_branding_block(&$variables)` but `$variables` does not contain the block entity. How can I get the block in this preprocess function so that I can load my added value with `$block->getThirdPartySetting`?

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: You can override the system branding block template via the block--system-branding-block.html.twig file (instead of using a preprocess hook).

On a Bootstrap theme, block--system-branding-block.html.twig looks like this:

```
{% block content %}
  {% if site_logo %}
    <a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">
      <img src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" />
    </a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_name %}
    <a class="name navbar-brand" href="{{ path('<front>') }}" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home">{{ site_name }}</a>
  {% endif %}
  {% if site_slogan %}
    <p class="navbar-text">{{ site_slogan }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

You can alter the href of those links to point anywhere you'd like, for example:

```
<a class="logo navbar-btn pull-left" href="/some/other/page" title="{{ 'Home'|t }}" rel="home"><src="{{ site_logo }}" alt="{{ 'Home'|t }}" /></a>
```

Comment: I already alter the block theme file. But I need the url come from the new field added to the block config. I don't want to have it fixed in the twig file.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry I missed that part of you question.